# Stub a module which exports a function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, stub, proxyquire

I need to replace the function returns by a module.

I'm using **CommonJS** with **nodejs 18**.

**index.js**

```js
const sinon = require("sinon");
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

const fileConverter = require("./file-converter");

async function main() {
  // Anyway, here is the way I did it for now:
  sinon.stub(fs.promises, "readFile").withArgs("test").returns("File content");

  sinon
    .stub(axios, "get")
    .withArgs("/codec-parameters?type=json")
    .resolves("File decoder");

  const result = await fileConverter.fromFilePath("test");
  console.log(result);
}

main();
```

**file-converter.js**

```js
const getCodec = require("./file-converter-codec");
const fs = require("fs");

class FileConverter {
  #codecs;

  #filePath;

  constructor(filePath) {
    this.#filePath = filePath;
  }

  async convert() {
    const fileContent = await fs.promises.readFile(this.#filePath);
    const codec = await getCodec("json");
    return codec.decode(fileContent);
  }
}

async function fromFilePath(filePath) {
  const fileParsed = new FileConverter(filePath);
  return await fileParsed.convert();
}

module.exports = {
  fromFilePath,
};
```

**file-converter-codec.js**

```js
const axios = require("axios");

class FileConverterCodec {
  #parameters;

  constructor(parameters) {
    this.#parameters = parameters;
  }

  decode(data) {
    return "File has been decoded";
  }
}

module.exports = async (type) => {
  const parameters = await axios.get(`/codec-parameters?type=${type}`);
  return new FileConverterCodec(parameters);
};
```

How can I stub the getCodec method that is called from inside of the class FileConverter? As the class FileConverter is not exported, I don't know how to do it. I want to prevent it from calling a REST API dependency

Is my reasoning correct if I include Axios directly here and stub it before it gets required from the file-converter-codec.js? I didn't want to stub Axios directly, which is called 2 modules deeper.

I prefer to stub a level under the file to be tested, no more! Otherwise, unit testing would require examining very deeply the sparse code in the case of a huge project. Is it correct? If it's correct then how can I stub a module that exports a function directly, like the one in the file-converter-codec.js?

[Codesandbox of this example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-night-4dt8ll)

*Note that I cannot modify the source code of the required module to add a name to it. Otherwise, I would have already done it.*

Comment: This example doesn't make sense because you mock the module you directly require. In this case you could just replace requiredModuleStubbed() with stubbedFunction() because test code is fully under your control, and this test also wouldn't make sense because you test what you wrote a line above. proxyquire arguments are for replacing the dependencies that "./my-required-module" requires, not "./my-required-module" module itself. If you have a specific real-world problem, consider updating the question with relevant details

Comment: @EstusFlask I updated the Codesandbox with a with an example closer to what I have in reality. I wrote my questions in the index.js file. Here the link again  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-night-4dt8ll

Comment: Please, update the question, it needs to contain all relevant information even if the link becomes unavailable. In your case it would be `proxyquire("./file-converter", { "./file-converter-codec": stubbedFunction })`. It makes sense to mock axios instead. It's unclear which kind of test you're writing, but unit test is supposed to be fast and doesn't involve anything that's not currently tested unit. So both third-party libs (axios) and network requests are supposed to be mocked. There are several testing helpers for axios that make it easier to mock